# Query getting null

Tags: java, html, jquery, jsp

```
 public List<User>usryearlyreport(int uid, int comp_id){
     List<User> userAll = new ArrayList<User>();
    User user;
  try{
      Statement myStatement = connection.createStatement();
      String query = "SELECT competency.comp_name as compname,sum(answer.ass_ans/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question where question.comp_id = "+comp_id+")) as assmarks, "
              + "sum(answer.eval_ans/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question where question.comp_id = "+comp_id+")) as evamarks FROM `answer` \n" +
                        "join taketest on taketest.testid=answer.testid\n" +
                        "join question on question.ques_id=answer.quesid \n" +
                        "join competency on competency.comp_id=question.comp_id\n" +
                        "where taketest.userid =" +uid+"\n"+
                        "group by competency.comp_id";
      ResultSet myRs = myStatement.executeQuery(query);
        while (myRs.next()) {
            user = new User();
             user.setCompname(myRs.getString("compname"));
             user.setAssmarks(myRs.getInt("assmarks"));
             user.setEvamarks(myRs.getInt("evamarks"));
            userAll.add(user);

        }
  }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception is ;" + e);
    }
   return userAll;   
}   }
```

I am using this query to get marks as per the image that I have attached besides. [mark table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzRe1.png)
It showing error because it couldn't read the (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question where question.comp_id = "+comp_id+"). When I replace the +comp_id" with the number it works. I think the comp_id giving null. What should I do for it? I have also attached certain database tables. [database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR1Wc.png)

```
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Competency Name</th>
                            <th>Self</th>
                            <th>Superior</th>
                            <th>Average</th>
                            <th>Level</th>
                            <th>Training Status</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <% 
                               String selfdataPoints=null;
                               String superiordataPoints=null;
                               String avgdataPoints=null;
                               int  totalavg =0;
                               int  totalself = 0;
                               int totalsuperior =0;
                               int uid;
                               int comp_id;
                             
                               String str="";
                              FormulaDAO fdao = new FormulaDAO();
                                  Formula fm = fdao.getAverageFormula();
                                 String fmla = fm.getFormula();
                                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                 //out.print(urole);
                                 
                                     uid =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));      
                                     comp_id =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")); 
                                 
         UserDAO userdao = new UserDAO();                     
         List<User> userall = userdao.usryearlyreport(uid,comp_id);
         Iterator<User> iterator = userall.iterator();
         int i=1;
                              while(iterator.hasNext()){
                                  User userdet = iterator.next(); String level,status;
                                  int aa = userdet.getAssmarks();
                                  int bb = userdet.getEvamarks();
                                  String a =Integer.toString(aa),b=Integer.toString(bb);
                                  String ee=fmla.replaceAll("a",a).replaceAll("b", b);
                                  int r=fdao.evaluateFormula(ee);                                      
                                   
                                   str= "{type:'stackedBar',showInLegend: true,name:'"+userdet.getCompname()+"'"
                                           + ",dataPoints:[{y:"+aa+",label:'self'},{y:"+r+",label:'average'},{y:"+bb+",label:'superior'}]},";
                                   sb.append(str);
                                  if(r>80){
                                      level= "Provision";
                                      status ="Meet requirements";
                                  }else{
                                      level= "Adequate";
                                      status="Need training";
                                  }
                            %>      
                            <tr>
                                <td><%=i%></td>
                                <td><%=userdet.getCompname()%></td>
                                <td><%=userdet.getAssmarks()%></td>
                                <td><%=userdet.getEvamarks()%></td>
                                <td><%=ee%>=<%=r%></td>
                                <td><%=level%></td> 
                                <td><%=status%></td>
                            </tr>   
                             <%
                                 i++;
                                 }

                              %>
```

The above coding is where I will retrieve a table using the "usryearlyreport" dao. Now I only need to know why the (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question where question.comp_id = "+comp_id+") this query doesn't support comp_id.

Comment: From where are you getting this `comp_id =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")); ` ?  are you using form to submit these datas ?

Comment: Yes I had used a form to submit those datas

Comment: Please show that as well . Also , make sure `name` use in input matches with `request.getParameter("id")` i.e : `id` .

Comment: Ok i'll check first